# How to define a static url in app.yaml "Google App Engine"?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I am trying to make an ajax call in my project to the file in the root directory named `abc.php`. This ajax call gets succeed when I try it on local server. But on server it gives `500 server error`.

I think the problem is that I need to set the static url in `app.yaml`. According to the given [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref#handlers_element). I implemented the following code:

```
handlers:

- url: /abc
  script: abc.php

# Serve images as static resources.
- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|css|js|pdf|woff|woff2|eot|svg|ttf|ico))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|css|js|pdf|woff|woff2|eot|svg|ttf|ico)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

But I am still not able to access `abc` url on server.
Can anyone please tell what is wrong with it?

Comment: Can you post the Google Appengine Logs for the request that is failing?

Comment: Hey @yydl, Thanks for the response. I have detected the reason and managed to run it properly. Basically curl was needed to be enabled and headers were needed to be passed. Which fixed this issue.